# SOLR : How to make solr filter on collapsed result set

Tags: solr

I have a problem using SOLR Collapse which gives me unexpected result.

Assuming  travellers:

```
{ traveller_id: 1, geo_hash: 4_u3bu, start_time: 2016-07-14T23:59:00Z },
{ traveller_id: 1, geo_hash: 4_de5f, start_time: 2018-07-14T23:59:00Z },
{ traveller_id: 2, geo_hash: 4_u3bu, start_time: 2018-07-14T23:59:00Z },
```

Basically I got 2 fq in my query like the followings...

The first one groups document by traveller id having most recent start time.

```
fq={!collapse field=traveller_id min=ms(now,start_time) }
```

At this point, when I only add that filter in my query, I get the following result:

```
 { traveller_id: 1, geo_hash: 4_de5f, start_time: 2018-07-14T23:59:00Z},
 { traveller_id: 2, geo_hash: 4_u3bu, start_time: 2018-07-14T23:59:00Z},
```

Looks good... But, wait!

If I also add an extra fq to only get the documents with a particular geohash, within the latter below:

```
fq=geohash: (4_u3bu)
```

Then the results becomes incorrect:

```
{ traveller_id: 1, geo_hash: 4_u3bu, start_time: 2016-07-14T23:59:00Z },
{ traveller_id: 2, geo_hash: 4_u3bu, start_time: 2018-07-14T23:59:00Z },
```

Looks like solr started by picking up the traveller with geohash: 4_u3bu and only then does the grouping.

Why is that ? I expected Solr to first group by most recent traveller and then applying the geohash filter...

Result expected is:

```
{ traveller_id: 2, geo_hash: 4_u3bu, start_time: 2018-07-14T23:59:00Z },
```

Is there anyway to solve that ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

even though it is used in a fq, the collapsing query parser it is not actually filtering out any document out, it just groups them by traveller_id, and then selects a single doc from each group as head of the group.

So this result is expected, when you apply fq=geohash: (4_u3bu), only two docs are returned by this, and then collapse does nothing at all on this result, as the two docs each form a group, there is nothing to collapse...

To do what you want try this: it might work by making the second fq exectute later (dont have much time now to test)

```
fq={!collapse field=traveller_id min=ms(now,start_time)}&fq={cache=false cost=200}geohash: (4_u3bu)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can i get the expected result?? I need to group by traveller id and then apply a filter on each head of group. How can i do that with solr ?

Comment: added something

Comment: Thanks.
Just tried this but it does not work unfortunately
`fq={!collapse field=traveller_id min=ms(now,start_time)}&fq={!cache=false cost=200}geohash: (4_u3bu)` still returning the travellers with older date time

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to use  a custom plug in which will do the filtering after the grouping is done.